# Print a string object using System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

My project needs to print a simple string object to a printer of choice using something like the WPF System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.

I created a standard System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument but it does not have a DocumentPaginator that is required for the PrintDocument() method belonging to the PrintDialog class.

This seems like a trivial task to print a string to a printer with a dialog to show printer choices, but is turning out significantly more difficult. Please Help!

Comment: i think you need add a handle to printPage event of PrintDocument https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-invoke-a-print-dialog) example?

Comment: The example shows printing of a XpsDocument. Do you have an example of how to make a XpsDocument from a string?

Comment: Henoc that is how I am currently printing using the PrintDocument class. You add a handler to it and provide the graphics. What I cannot get to work is using the PrintDialog with the PrintDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using WPF, instead of using the PrintDocument, just create a [FlowDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). I think that's a lot easier.

```
var dlg = new PrintDialog();
dlg.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
dlg.UserPageRangeEnabled = false;
if(dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{                
    var doc = new FlowDocument();
    // For normal A4&/letter pages, the defaults will print in two columns
    doc.ColumnWidth = dlg.PrintableAreaWidth;
    doc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("My arbitrary long string to print.\nNewlines work. Pages will break as needed.")));
    dlg.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator, "Simple document");
}
```